# JSON: Reuse JSON object inside another JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, reusability, code-reuse

Consider this JSON object, which may be used as options data for a select element in HTML:

```
{"dropdown_options" : [
          {"id" : "received", "title" : "Received", "value" : "received"},   
          {"id" : "approved", "title" : "Approved", "value" : "approved"}, 
          {"id" : "rejected", "title" : "Rejected", "value" : "rejected"}
]}
```

How can I reuse the above JSON object to define another JSON object?
Something like this:

```
{"select" : {"id" : "message_carriers", "options" : "dropdown_options"}}
```

**EDIT: The above code sample is part of a .json file.**

Comment: What you have is not a JSON object, it's an object defined via object literal syntax; http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: JSON does not support references, try YAML or XML

Comment: @Esailija: Nope, strictly JSON

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is

```
var jsonobj={"dropdown_options" : [{"id" : "received", "title" : "Received", "value" : "received"}, {"id" : "approved", "title" : "Approved", "value" : "approved"}, {"id" : "received", "title" : "Received", "value" : "received"}]};
var selectobj={"select" : {"id" : "message_carriers", "options" : jsonobj}}
```

Mind, that in the second line the variable name is given - so no quotes.

**Edit**

From comment I take, that the JSON objects are created from files. So, assuming that the first object is in `jsonobj` and the second (without the "options") in `selectobj`, you just need to

```
selectobj.options=jsonobj;
```

or

```
selectobj.options=jsonobj.dropdown_options;
```

to link them together, without the need for variables in the primary definition.

Comment: You might also want to look at `var selectobj={"select" : {"id" : "message_carriers", "options" : jsonobj.dropdown_options}}` to avoid unnecessary depth.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the above code sample in the question is in .json file. So cannot use variables, like you've mentioned in your answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. But what I needed was to reference a "JSON Object" from within the .JSON file without the need of manipulating the JSON definition in a seperate javascript file.

Comment: This is simply impossible. There is no mechanism to provide linkage between the contents of a .json file and the variables in the scope of the reding code. The easiest way should be to read the file into a string, convert it to a JS object, then manipulate it: This gives you a possibility to hook into "special strings" of your own making.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I know I could use javascript to accomplish this. I was only hoping there could be a solution like I was anticipating, similar to YAML way of referencing other definitions withing the same file. Anyway, thanks so much for your efforts @Eugen